# add_action works outside condition but not inside it

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a theme framework for my own purposes.

So this time i am facing a problem, that is add_action works out side conditional.

```
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_entry_header_structure_open', 5 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo "<div class='title_cat'>";}, 6 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo meanz_post_cats();}, 7 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_do_title', 25 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo "</div>";}, 49 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_do_thumbnail', 50 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_entry_header_structure_close', 100 );
```

Otherwise if is use a conditional like this, it doesn't work

```
if(is_single()){
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_entry_header_structure_open', 5 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo "<div class='title_cat'>";}, 6 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo meanz_post_cats();}, 7 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_do_title', 25 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', function(){echo "</div>";}, 49 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_do_thumbnail', 50 );
add_action( 'meanz_before_main_wrap', 'meanz_entry_header_structure_close', 100 );
}
```

Don't know why it doesn't work. Any comments?

Sorry for wrong code. Updated the question.

Comment: In the title you talk about `remove_action` but your code sample has `add_action`. As for your question, maybe they do not work because the condition is returning false!!??

Comment: updated the question